# How to crop non-projected EPGS:4326 polygons along straight lines?

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-sf, r-sp

I am trying to allocate spatial polygons to unevenly-sized boxes defined by decimal degree coordinates with the [sf package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html):

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(spData)
#> To access larger datasets in this package, install the spDataLarge
#> package with: `install.packages('spDataLarge',
#> repos='https://nowosad.github.io/drat/', type='source')`

x <- world 

plot(st_geometry(x), xlim = c(60,180), ylim = c(0, 60))

matrix(c(60, 0, 180, 0, 180, 30, 60, 30, 60, 0), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) %>%
  list() %>% st_polygon() %>% st_sfc() %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  plot(add = T, border = "red", col = NA, lwd = 3)

matrix(c(60, 30, 120, 30, 120, 60, 60, 60, 60, 30), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) %>%
  list() %>% st_polygon() %>% st_sfc() %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  plot(add = T, border = "blue", col = NA, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

I want to crop/split the contents of the blue and red boxes into separate entities. When I use the `st_crop` function, I notice that the cropping is done along curved lines coinciding with the edges of the underlying polygons of `x`:

```r
crop1 <- st_crop(x, xmin = 60, xmax = 180, ymin = 0, ymax = 30)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
crop2 <- st_crop(x, xmin = 60, xmax = 120, ymin = 30, ymax = 60)
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

plot(st_geometry(x), xlim = c(60,180), ylim = c(0, 60))
plot(st_geometry(crop1), border = "red", col = NA, add = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(crop2), border = "blue", col = NA, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It seems that the coordinates are not handled planar as stated [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf6.html#although-coordinates-are-longitudelatitude-xxx-assumes-that-they-are-planar), but perhaps projected before cropping (?). Also, one could reduce the curvature by adding [nodes to the underlying polygons before cropping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376019/st-crop-follow-latitudinal-circle-on-polar-projection). While this may be required when further projecting the cropped object, it seems unnecessarily complicated way as opposed to just doing the cropping by assuming lon/lat values as cartesian coordinates.

Is there (an easy) way to crop the decimal degree polygons assuming cartesian coordinates (i.e. along straight lines) in `sf`? I am mostly concerned by the resulting overlap of polygons when they are uneven in size.

**EDIT**

`sp` and `rgeos` do not seem to have this problem:

````r
``` r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
#> rgeos version: 0.5-7, (SVN revision (unknown))
#>  GEOS runtime version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2 
#>  GEOS using OverlayNG
#>  Linking to sp version: 1.4-5 
#>  Polygon checking: TRUE
library(spData)
#> To access larger datasets in this package, install the spDataLarge
#> package with: `install.packages('spDataLarge',
#> repos='https://nowosad.github.io/drat/', type='source')`

y <- as_Spatial(world)
rect1 <- matrix(c(60, 0, 180, 0, 180, 30, 60, 30, 60, 0), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) %>%
  list() %>% st_polygon() %>% st_sfc() %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% as_Spatial()
rect2 <- matrix(c(60, 30, 120, 30, 120, 60, 60, 60, 60, 30), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) %>%
  list() %>% st_polygon() %>% st_sfc() %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% as_Spatial()

sp::plot(y, xlim = c(60,180), ylim = c(0, 60))
sp::plot(rgeos::gIntersection(y, rect1, byid = TRUE), add = TRUE, border = "red", col = NA)
sp::plot(rgeos::gIntersection(y, rect2, byid = TRUE), add = TRUE, border = "blue", col = NA)
````

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: What version of sf are you using? There has been a change of geometry backend around v1 (GEOS >> s2) that may be relevant in your use case

Comment: @JindraLacko 1.0.2

Comment: `st_intersection` seems to have the same issue. Is this a bug or an intended artifact of GEOS?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1780