# How to extract a part of an sf shape in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-sf

Say that I have the `sf` type shape data of the US.

```
usa <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country="USA")
# nrow(usa) is 1
```

Now the `usa` data provided by the package `giscoR` includes Alaska and some Pacific islands. Is there any way to extract the contiguous USA as a smaller `sf` data from the whole shape? Or can I just plot the contiguous USA within the `ggplot` + `geom_sf` framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sf::st_crop` to trim the co-ordinates to whichever you choose, then plot however you like. Here's a full reprex using `ggplot`:

```r
giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = "USA") |>
  sf::st_crop(c(xmin = -125, xmax = -60, ymin = 20, ymax = 60)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot() + 
  ggplot2::geom_sf()
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: while this answer is correct in the narrow sense that it works I suggest avoiding using `sf::st_crop()` on unprojected coordinates in s2 context - it interpret the crop in a spherical manner, ie. will crop not along "straight" lines, but along great circles. This may lead to unexpected results, see this question and especially the GitHub issue linked in comments
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027136/how-to-crop-non-projected-epgs4326-polygons-along-straight-lines

Answer (score 1):

The output you describe - a single row of data at country level - is the expected behavior of *country* (ie. national) level data. Both Alaska and the pacific islands (Hawaii I presume) are parts of the USA.

To get the lower 48 separately you may wish to start with sub-national administrative units, such as the US states, and filter them out as required. A good place would be the `{tigris}` package.

So consider this piece of code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

states <- states(cb = FALSE, resolution = '20m') %>%
  filter(!STUSPS %in% c('HI', 'AK', 'PR', 'GU', 'VI', 'AS', 'MP')) %>% 
  select(NAME, STUSPS) 


ggplot(data = states) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = STUSPS)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Once you have 48 states object prepared you can merge it to a single multipolygon geometry via a `dplyr::summarise()` call.

```r
lower_48 <- states %>% 
  summarise()

ggplot(data = lower_48) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]